# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException Error in C#

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to solve this problem and I would appreciate a little insight into exactly what I'm doing wrong here. I am trying to loop through the array spaces and add an item to the array allwords that is a substring of the string words. Spaces and words are the same length, spaces simply has the white spaces in words listed in ascending order (starting at 1). Not sure if that made any sense, let me know if it didn't so I can try to clarify it a little. I keep getting the error message: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Index and length must refer to a location within the string. (Parameter 'length') whenever I run this program. Additionally, I noticed that it will run the first few loops, but never goes above 3. I have been trying to fix it for hours to no avail, so thanks for taking a look!

I have also tried for and while loops, in response to the comments.

```
string[] allwords = new string[wordcount];
  allwords[0] = words.Substring(0, Array.IndexOf(spaces, 1));
    while (k<(wordcount))
    {
       int u = Array.IndexOf(spaces, k);
       int o = Array.IndexOf(spaces, (k+1));
       allwords[k] = words.Substring(u, o);
       k++;
    }
    allwords[(wordcount-1)] = words.Substring(Array.IndexOf(spaces, wordcount), spaces.Length);
```

Comment: I would recommend using a for loop instead of while. it looks like the values you pass on to Substring are wrong. have you done any debugging? place a breakpoint in the loop and follow the execution.

Comment: You should consider those two cases: 1) if `words` have no space, all the codes under the line 2 should not be there; 2) if `words` only have one space. the codes in `while` loop should not be executed. Then you may avoid the exception.